# concept and advantages of Transient and Non-Transient memory in ARM?

Tags: memory, arm, cpu-architecture, mmu

In the ARM architecture Manual it is mentioned that the cache can be transient and non transient and it is implementation defined. I am failing to understand the concept and use of transient memory with respect to cache. I am trying to write software for enabling MMU and I have already enabled the L1 and L2 cache. I am using the LPAE. I know that MAIR register controls this attribute. I am failing to get any good documentation about it.

I want to know the concept so that I want to check the feasibility of applying it to the present design.

arm-v7-a-r page 134

"For an ARMv7-A implementation that includes the Large Physical Address Extension, it is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED whether a Transient attribute is supported for cacheable Normal memory regions. If an implementation supports this attribute, the set of possible cacheability attributes for a Normal memory region becomes:
• Write-Through Cacheable, Non-transient
• Write-Back Cacheable, Non-transient
• Write-Through Cacheable, Transient
• Write-Back Cacheable, Transient
• Non-cacheable."

Comment: random guess: "transient" means a memory region tends not to have a useful amount of temporal locality.  i.e. you can cache it, but you probably shouldn't evict lines from other regions.  e.g. maybe insert "transient" lines into cache in the LRU position of a set (instead of the usual MRU position), so it's next in line to be evicted.

Comment: Did you see the sentence right after the part you quoted? _"The transient attribute indicates that the benefit of caching is for a relatively short period, and that therefore it might be better to restrict allocation, to avoid possibly casting-out other, less transient, entries."_ - that's about all there is to it. Does "I am trying to implement an MMU" mean you're actually designing hardware, or merely writing software to _use_ the MMU? In the latter case, the very first consideration would be whether the system(s) you're targeting even support the transient hint; most don't.

Comment: I am "merely writing software to use the MMU". Do you  mean that there should be special hardware support for this to be implemented or it is implementation defined. Like I put a timer and erase the cache after a time.

Comment: My first comment was based on the assumption that you were designing hardware to implement these semantics.  Based on Notlikethat's comment, it seems I was right, and that my suggestion would be a reasonable implementation.  Assume that the hardware works something like that.  It won't intentionally invalidate the cache for no reason based on a timer; that would have no upside.  When writing software, probably just place data with low reuse value in a "transient" memory region.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ARM ARM says, shortly after the part you've quoted:

> The transient attribute indicates that the benefit of caching is for a relatively short period, and that therefore it might be better to restrict allocation, to avoid possibly casting-out other, less transient, entries.

In other words, it's a hint to the cache system. [As Peter suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636326/concept-and-advantages-of-transient-and-non-transient-memory-in-arm#comment64661366_38636326), when the cache has a predictable replacement policy (e.g. LRU or round-robin) this could be implemented by allocating straight into positions which are already very close to eviction. Another alternative is for transient/non-temporal accesses to only allocate into lower levels of cache, as those typically represent less recently used data than whatever's hot in L1.

That has a theoretical benefit to certain streaming-type workloads - for example, by mapping large data buffers as cacheable but transient, a processing algorithm working through those buffers could still benefit from the cache in terms of access locality (i.e. multiple hits in the same line) and automatic prefetching of subsequent lines for regular access patterns, but without thrashing and disrupting instruction fetches, stack accesses, etc. in the rest of the cache. On the other hand, though, most modern caches are clever enough to at least detect sustained regular access patterns of writes and automatically enter a non-allocating streaming mode, which gives some of the same benefit completely transparently without needing the programmer to muck about with attributes.

From a practical perspective, the most important concern is whether it's worth worrying about at all: in general, it isn't. Having had a quick look through some TRMs, Cortex-A7 [ignores the transient attribute entirely](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464f/B4BEIDGHFH.html); Cortex-A15 [might actually go wrong if you try to use it](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0438i/CACFEBDD.html); [Cortex-A12/17](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0535c/index.html) and Marvell's v7 core (per the [public Armada XP functional spec](http://www.marvell.com/embedded-processors/armada-xp/)) don't seem to mention it at all, so in the absence of any specific implementation-specific definition I'd guess they may well ignore it too (particularly since they also mention pseudo-random cache replacement policies). I've no idea about Qualcomm Krait or any other implementations, as public documentation isn't forthcoming.

From what little I know about CPU design, the transient attribute has the impression of being one of those features which not only offers no benefit outside a very particular niche, but also adds a comparatively large cost to the design and verification. In other words, I doubt anyone's going there without a very specific requirement, although the fact that it exists in the architecture at all means there's almost certainly *some* hardware out there running *some* workload that is better off for implementing it. Unless you already know you have that hardware and that workload, though, then I'd be inclined to simply forget about it.

Comment: That was pretty detailed. Thanks